# Can Email Headers contain international characters?

Tags: sql, smtp

I am deciding if I should waste space using an NVarchar in my SQL Database. If email headers do not support all characters anyway then I will just store as Varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today the headers in their raw form does not contain anything other than US-ASCII characters. Of course one can enter (almost) any Unicode characters into some headers, e.g. Subject, name part of the From, To, etc, but these are encoded  using special forms of Base64 or Quoted-Printable encoding. So the answer to your question depends on the format your system will use to store headers:

1. raw format: appropriate for debugging, exact reproduction of the headers, etc., it contains US-ASCII only, but unreadable.
2. decoded format: readable, but it may contain almost any Unicode characters.

On the other hand there is already an [experimental RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335) which defines real UTF-8 headers, so all of the above may change within a few years.

Answer (score 2):

Yes They Can, via several different encoding mechanisms called out in the relevant RFCs.